# Hide a number in an EditText after type it

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have 4 EditText boxes to input a PIN number, like this:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/input_login_pin1"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/input_login_pin"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/input_login_pin"
        android:background="@drawable/input_pin"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="textPassword|number"
        android:maxLength="1"/>
```

The behaviour I want to achieve is the following: when the user types his first number in the first box, hide it(like a password) and move to the next box.

To move the input to the next box I am using a method that just changes the focus to the next box after user types it, don't a problem with that.

```
pin1ET.addTextChangedListener(inputTextWatcher1);

private TextWatcher inputTextWatcher1 = new TextWatcher() {
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
    { }
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            pin2ET.requestFocus();
   }
```

My problem is that the numbers are not being hidden until the user hides the keyboard (When he completes the 4 boxes), and I want to hide the number automatically after he types the number.

I have a solution, hide the keyboard after the user types the number in one box and display again when the focus moves to the next box.

But it is not the best one. I would really appreciate your opinion and see if someone has a better solution.

Comment: Don't you should place `pin2ET.requestFocus()` on `afterTextChanged()` instead of `onTestChanged()` ?

Comment: onTextChanged is when user type the number, it works well. What I want to achieve is hide the number in the box after the user types it

Answer (score 0):

```
//first, we create an EditText
EditText answer = new EditText(this);
```

//second, we create the TextWatcher

```
TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
       answer.setText("");

    }
};
```

//third, we must add the `textWatcher` to our `EditText`

```
answer.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
```

Comment: I am not sure the purpose of that, If I set the text to "", when I will get all the pin number will be ""